# examples for hibernate.max_fetch_depth example

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a big database with bidirectional relationships all over the place. the problem is when I pass a classic jpa query like findById or other I recover objects with infinite depths (in short I recover my entire database). so my question is:
Is there a way to limit the depth of retrieved objects? is the following hibernate property useful?

> **hibernate.max_fetch_depth**

> *Sets a maximum "depth" for the outer join fetch tree for single-ended associations (one-to-one, many-to-one). A 0 disables default outer join fetching. e.g. recommended values between 0 and 3*

can someone explain this property to me with examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate lets you decide the depth of fetches in case of `EAGER` fetches in your Entity classes.

Consider an example:

```
public class ClassA implements Serializable{
@JoinColumn(name="class_b", referenceColumnName="id")
@ManyToOne
private ClassB classB;
}

public class ClassB implements Serializable{
@JoinColumn(name="class_c", referenceColumnName="id")
@ManyToOne
private ClassC classC;
}

public class ClassC implements Serializable{
@JoinColumn(name="class_d", referenceColumnName="id")
@ManyToOne
private ClassD classD;
}


public class ClassD implements Serializable{
//codes
}
```

If you  fetch ClassA, and your `hibernate.max_fetch_depth` is set to 2, it will only ClassB and then classB will fetch ClassC and the fetching  process is terminated.

You can look at this [Document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/configuration-optional.html) for more information.